# Java, How to break a loop when input is empty?

Tags: java, break

The goal of this is to let the user enter a number per line and when the user no longer wish to continue they should be able to enter a empty line and when that happens the program should you give you a message with the largest number.

Problem is I can't make the loop break with an empty line. I'm not sure how to. I've checked other questions for a solution but I couldn't find anything that helped. I also can't assign `scan.hasNextInt() == null`....

I'm sure there is a quick and logical solution to this that I'm not thinking of.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number and press [Enter] per line, when you no longer wish to continue press [Enter] with no input.(empty line)");
        int x = 0;

        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            int n = scan.nextInt();

            if (n > x){
               x = n;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largets number entered: " + x);

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `Scanner#hasNextLine()` and `Scanner#nextLine()` to get input and check if that string is empty. If it is, you can break the loop, if it isn't you can try parsing the input to `int` and do other logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number and press [Enter] per line, when you no longer wish to continue press [Enter] with no input.");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        int x = 0;

        try {
            while(!str.isEmpty()){
                int number = Integer.parseInt(str);

                if (number > x){
                    x = number;
                }

                str = scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }
         catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             System.out.println("There was an exception. You entered a data type other than Integer");
         }

        System.out.println("Largets number entered: " + x);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It does what OP asked for. Though it would be better if there where some explanations and a try-catch for the possible `NumberFormatException` that gets thrown when the user enters anything else but a number.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number and press [Enter] per line, when you no longer wish to continue press [Enter] with no input.(empty line)");
        int x = 0;

        try {
            while(!scan.nextLine().isEmpty()){
                int num = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

                if(num > x) {
                    x = num;
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Largest number entered: " + x);
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you could add a try-catch block to handle possible `NumberFormatExceptions` and break out of the loop? Just a question of having a complete Answer.